# addition of editext values always returns zero

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

i have 10 edittext values in activitya,i want to add them and show the result in newactivity.

my code

```
    public class activitya extends Activity implements onclicklistener
    {
      private EditText editext1;
      private EditText editext2;
      private EditText editext3;
      private EditText editext4;
      private EditText editext5;
      private Button calculate;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitya);
            calculate =(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button1);
            calculate.setonclicklistener(this);

          }

       public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
      onadd();
      break;
      default:
      break;
   }

     }
public void onadd()
{

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String value1 = editext1.getText().toString();
    String value2 =editext2.getText().toString();
    bundle.putString("sendvalue1",value1));
    bundle.putString("sendvalue2",value2));

      try{
     Double Total =Double.parseDouble(value1)+Double.parseDouble(value2);}
      catch(NumberFormatException e)
     {
      e.printstacktrace();
      }
     bundle.putString("totalvalue",String.valueof(Total));

   Intent a = new intent(this,newactivity.class);
    a.putExtras(bundle);
    startactivity(a);

   }
   }
```

in newactivity :

```
 public class newactivity extends activity{
  private TextView total;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        total =(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.text1);
    onview();

}

   public void onview()
 {
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String param1 = bundle.getString("totalvalue");
        total.setText(param1);

 }
```

it shows the addition correctly only if i enter all the 10 values, strange 
if i dont enter even one value it shows zero,
couldnt understand where the problem is

Comment: Put all 10 values and log also

Comment: I bet you've got a try catch somewhere surrounding this and you do nothing in the catch.  Double.parseDouble is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a try-catch and you do nothing in the catch.  This is usually bad practice since you do not know when anything happens in your code.

In this case, Double.parseDouble is throwing an exception as you are trying to parse empty Strings.  `""` cannot be parsed to a double.  `"0"` can.

You need to make sure that every edit text contains a valid value which can parse to a double or, test each value before trying to parse it.

Comment: checked for null values and put zero if null before passing to bundle.

Answer (score 0):

To check all `EditText` length before you add all the values.

Like,

```
if(EditText1.getText.length()==0){
 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"All fields are mandatory ",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else if(EditText2.getText.length()==0){
} else if(){
..........
 }else{
 }
```

You will avoid `NullPointerException`

Comment: i dont get a nullpointer exception, addition always returns zero if i leave even one value